# Session item always null in asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

The function to upload image:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public String UploadSingle(HttpPostedFileBase imageFile)
    {
        try
        {
            String fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Temp/" +
               imageFile.FileName);
            imageFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);

            List<String> uploadedFile = (List<String>)HttpContext.Session["UploadedFiles"];
            if (uploadedFile == null)
            {
                uploadedFile = new List<string>();
            }

            uploadedFile.Add(fileSavePath);
            HttpContext.Session["UploadedFiles"] = uploadedFile;
            return "Success";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "Error";
        }
    }
```

This function work okay, the image is uploaded. But when i try to see the uploaded images.

```
 public String UploadResult()
    {
        List<String> uploadedFile = (List<String>)HttpContext.Session["UploadedFiles"];

        return uploadedFile.Count + "";
    }
```

When i debug, the HttpContext.Session["UploadedFiles"] always return null.
Please give me some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HttpContext.Current.Session["UploadedFiles"]` instead of `HttpContext.Session["UploadedFiles"]`

`HttpContext.Current.Session` simply returns null if there is no session available.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `HttpContext.Session["UploadedFiles"]` just use `Session["UploadedFiles"]`

it will work